# Process of finding the derivative of a function with respect to two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

I have been studying introductory calculus for a while and on the side I study chemistry. The other day I was messing around with thermodynamics and so I wanted to find the change in vollume if a air duct changes its radius and length. But I am stuck because I have no idea how to figure that out. I am using the equation:
$$V = \pi r^2 h$$
How could I find the derivative of the vollume when the height (h) and radius (r) change?

Comment: Do you mean $$V=V(r,p)$$?

Comment: Are you varying one at a time or both at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to assume that $r$ and $h$ are functions of some as of yet unidentified parameter.

And then apply the product rule.

$v' = \pi (2rr') h + \pi r^2 h'$

And then you can decide after the fact how much you want $r$ and $h$ to vary and see the impact on $v'$

You could also write it as: $dv = (\pi 2rh)dr + (\pi r^2) dh$